# c# Default datetime? method parameter where nulls mean something

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a method with a bunch of defaulted datetime? parameters. I would like to be able to process nulls. I mean, if a caller passes in a null, I would like to process it as well.

So, I don't want to write:

```
public void MethodName(DateTime? signedConsent2 = null) {
}
```

I tried:

```
public void MethodName(DateTime? signedConsent2 = (DateTime?)default(DateTime)) {
}
```

but I am getting "The default parameter must be a compile time constant".

First off, I don't understand why `default(DateTime)` is a compile time constant but `(DateTime?)default(DateTime)` is not. Second off, is there any solution for this problem aside form overloading methods (which would be a lot of work since I have so many arguments).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be able to solve this problem by declaring a constant in a `Constants` class, like `const DefaultTime = new Nullable<DateTime>("1/2/2000");` and then reference it like `public void MethodName(DateTime? signedConsent2 = Constants.DefaultTime)` I don't have a compiler handy to verify, though.

Comment: @neontapir `The type 'System.DateTime?' cannot be declared const`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need two overloads of your method:

```
public void MethodName()
{
    MethodName(default(DateTime));
}

public void MethodName(DateTime? signedConsent2)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking to handle multiple scenarios. Like calling the method as:

```
MethodName();
MethodName(null); //or MethodName(default(DateTime?));
```

Where calling it without parameter means something different than call it with `null` or `DateTime?` value.

In that case You have **no other option but to define two overloads.** You can't handle that with *default parameter*. There is no way for you to know whether method is called without a parameter or with a valid `DateTime?` parameter holding `null` value. In either case you will end up with `null` in your parameter.

```
public void MethodName()
{
    //Method without any parameter called
    MethodName(default(DateTime?));// call overload
}
public void MethodName(DateTime? signedConsent2 = default(DateTime?))
{
}
```

or  `public void MethodName(DateTime? signedConsent2 = null)`

For:

> First off, I don't understand why default(DateTime) is a compile time
>   constant but (DateTime?)default(DateTime) is not.

The second code `(DateTime?)default(DateTime)` is doing an explicit cast which is a runtime operation and hence the error.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that changing from a default parameter to a parameterless overload with a _different_ "default" may not work without rebuilding clients. Clients compiled against the method with a default parameter will _not_ use the parameterless overload.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the parameters like you did at first:

```
public void MethodName(DateTime? signedConsent2 = null) {
}
```

and then when it's time to use them, coalesce the default:

```
var x = signedConsent2 ?? default(DateTime);
```

One advantage to this is, you may change your defaults, and you won't have to change the method signature. That's a good thing.

Comment: I think OP wants to `null` to mean something distinct from default(datetime).

Comment: @Blorgbeard then he can put whatever he wants after the ??

Comment: No, I mean I think he wants `MethodName()` (no parameter) to act differently to `MethodName(null)`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I didn't read it that way at all. Perhaps he can weigh in.

Comment: Then habibhas your answer.